# check file in database?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have this code

```
lblSignFile.Visible = False
        oSDR = objDB.CreateSDRFromSQLSelect("select signfile from appuserdtl where uid ='" & sUID & "'")
        Dim chkFile As New IO.FileInfo(oSDR.ToString)
        If chkFile.Exists() = True Then

            lblSignFile.Visible = True
            lblSignFile.Text = "Yes"
        ElseIf chkFile.Exists() = False Then

            lblSignFile.Visible = True
            lblSignFile.Text = "No"
        End If
    End If
```

i want check the file in after insert in databse sql server..and then in the form asp.net i want show status that file with component label.. please helpme..

regards arif pratama

Comment: where is your insert code?

Comment: What happens when you run this code? The problem probably is in `CreateSDRFromSQLSelect()`, which is not a framework method.

Comment: it is the code to display the status if a file has been uploaded already exists in the database .. but why always only status false that naturally arises in the application form .. for files already exist in databasa .. I just wanted to show you if the file already exists in the database which then uploads lblSignFile be YES .. and vice versa

Comment: codeCaster...lblsignfile always show NO although existing data in the database

Answer (score 0):

You can determine whether a specified file exists using the Exists method of the `File` class in the `System.IO` namespace:

```
bool System.IO.File.Exists(string path)
```

try this in your code.... and check